# Why am I not allowed to install my dependencies with composer?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I try running the command "composer install" within my laravel project. I get this error message:

[image]

As far as I know, the ezsystems/ezplatform package isn't even in my composer.json file.

Here is the ezsystems/ezplatform package github link:
https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform

Below is my `composer.json` file:

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error message as text rather than an image. That way, future users with the same error can search for it (as you hopefully have already), and users on small screens or with visual impairments can still help you.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. I just updated Drupal core to 8.9.5 just fine with no issues. However, when I try to update a single module I get this issue.

[RuntimeException] Could not load package ezsystems/ezplatform in http://repo.packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint dev-load-varnish-only-when-used as ^2.0@dev: Invalid version string "^2.0@dev"
[UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint dev-load-varnish-only-when-used as ^2.0@dev: Invalid version string "^2.0@dev"

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Looks like any of your packages depends on that package in question

Comment: I'm getting the same error with a brand new install of everything. `composer` appears to be working correctly but `laravel new mySite` errors out. There is no mention of `ezsystems` in my composer.json file either.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a problem with composer, see: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9191
Rollback your composer version `composer selfupdate --rollback`

Comment: [UnexpectedValueException]
  Composer rollback failed: no installation to roll back to in "C:/Users/%%USER%%/AppData/Roaming/Composer"

Comment: Try uninstall and fresh install an older version (<1.10.11)

Comment: Yeah I grabbed composer 1.9.3 phar file and ran the create-project command. Site is now installed. Thanks