# composer install --no-dev fails with package and dependency not required or set, ezsystems/ezplatform dependedn

Tags: composer-php

Composer install is failing with:

```
`Could not load package ezsystems/ezplatform in https://repo.packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint dev-load-varnish-only-when-used as ^2.0@dev: Invalid version string "^2.0@dev"`
```

The only problem is, we aren't calling that package...
Would anyone know how to figure out which package is causing the break?

Here's our composer.json file:

```
  "require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.92",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
    "psr/log": "^1.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.11",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "avalara/avataxclient": "*",
    "salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php": "*"
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "php": "^7.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "behat/mink": "^1.8",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
    "dmore/chrome-mink-driver": "^2.0",
    "ext-dom": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I not allowed to install my dependencies with composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798824/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-install-my-dependencies-with-composer)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved with:

`composer install self-update 1.10.10`

There was a glitch with the composer upgrade the other day.

Another fix is:

`composer install self-update`

This will update to 1.10.12 and bypass the error.