# composer could not load package Invalid version string

Tags: docker, symfony, composer-php

I faced with range case, when I was try to install some bundle in locally I faced with erro, but when I try install the same bundle in test server everything installed without error. I use docker-compose and install bundle inside in image. docker-copose and other docker file with all dependecies absolutelty the same, all in git.

`composer require league/flysystem-bundle`

and in locally I faced with that

Using version dev-master for league/flysystem-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not load package ezsystems/ezplatform in http://repo.packagist.org: [  
  UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint dev-load-varni  
  sh-only-when-used as ^2.0@dev: Invalid version string "^2.0@dev"             
                                                                               

                                                                               
  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  Could not parse version constraint dev-load-varnish-only-when-used as ^2.0@  
  dev: Invalid version string "^2.0@dev"
```

locally composer version Composer version 1.10.11 2020-09-08 16:53:44

and test server

```
/var/www/symfony # composer require league/flysystem-bundle
Using version dev-master for league/flysystem-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.0.*"

Prefetching 3 packages  
  - Downloading (100%)

Package operations: 3 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/flysystem (1.x-dev 53f16fd): Loading from cache
  - Installing league/flysystem-bundle (dev-master 525845a): Loading from cache
Package easycorp/easy-log-handler is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package zendframework/zend-code is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-code instead.
Package zendframework/zend-eventmanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-eventmanager instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
20 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (c67222ac592a52b7dec1c2cd56763685)
  -  WARNING  league/flysystem-bundle (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib:master
    The recipe for this package comes from the "contrib" repository, which is open to community contributions.
    Review the recipe at https://github.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/tree/master/league/flysystem-bundle/1.0

    Do you want to execute this recipe?
    [y] Yes
    [n] No
    [a] Yes for all packages, only for the current installation session
    [p] Yes permanently, never ask again for this project
    (defaults to n): 
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]
```

test server composer version Composer version 1.10.10 2020-08-03 11:35:19

my dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:edge

LABEL maintainer="Vincent Composieux <vincent.composieux@gmail.com>"

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    coreutils \
    yarn \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-apcu \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-curl \
    php7-dom \
    php7-gd \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-imagick \
    php7-json \
    php7-intl \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-fileinfo\
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-pgsql \
    php7-xml \
    php7-zlib \
    php7-phar \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-session \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-xdebug \
    php7-zip \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    make \
    curl \
    zlib-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    rabbitmq-c-dev \
    oniguruma-dev \
    php7-pecl-amqp \
    php7-amqp \
    php7-redis

RUN apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/ php7-pecl-mongodb

RUN echo "$(curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig) -" > composer-setup.php.sig \
        && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | tee composer-setup.php | sha384sum -c composer-setup.php.sig \
        && php composer-setup.php && rm composer-setup.php* \
        && chmod +x composer.phar && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

COPY symfony.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/
COPY symfony.ini /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/
COPY xdebug.ini  /etc/php7/conf.d/

COPY symfony.pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/

CMD ["php-fpm7", "-F"]

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony
EXPOSE 9001
```

Why in the same time I faced with differnt version composer. Composer installed by the same way, by the same Dockerfile. How to fix this problem ?
I don't belive, how it's possible, this problem don't should be appear when using docker structure.. ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I not allowed to install my dependencies with composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63798824/why-am-i-not-allowed-to-install-my-dependencies-with-composer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like composer 1.10.11 is broken. You can switch to 1.10.10 like this:

```
composer-setup.php --version=1.10.10
```

Comment: you right. problem was with new composer version 1.10.11. I reduced to 1.10.10 and lib installed

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed that error from composer 1.10.11. You should down to composer v1.10.10.

```
composer self-update 1.10.10
```

You can use self-update to downgrade composer version

Answer (score 0):

Now you can update your composer version to `1.10.12`

In this version you don't have this error.