# Composer error for CakePHP migrations plugin: UnexpectedValueException Could not parse version constraint

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I am currently getting this error when I try to build a docker container of a CakePHP3 PHP application:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not load package cakephp/migrations in http://repo.packagist.org: [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint 0.next-dev: Invalid version string "0.next-dev"



  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint 0.next-dev: Invalid version string "0.next-dev"


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

This is the relevant part of my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "cakephp/app",
    "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.5.*",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "1.7.*",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "*",
        "friendsofcake/search": "^2.3",
        "josegonzalez/cakephp-version": "1.*",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "friendsofcake/cakephp-csvview": "~3.0",
        "alt3/cakephp-swagger": "^2.0.2",
        "riesenia/cakephp-duplicatable": "^3.0",
        "dakota/cake-excel": "^2.0",
        "spomky-labs/jose": "^7.0",
        "burzum/cakephp-imagine-plugin": "2.*",
        "tightenco/collect": "< 5.7",
        "muffin/trash": "^2.1",
        "friendsofcake/crud": "^5.4",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~7.0"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

As you can see, the version of the `migrations` library is set to `"1.7.*"`, so I don't understand what could be possibly causing this error.

Comment: Is this your issue, or related? https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/448

Comment: @BadHorsie I checked the composer.json of the cakephp/migrations project for the 1.7.0, 1.7.1 and 1.7.2 tags and they all point explicitly to the 0.8.1 tag of phinx... so I don't think that's the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [composer could not load package Invalid version string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801165/composer-could-not-load-package-invalid-version-string)

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, it wsa indeed a bug in the Docker Composer image.